# How to get list of all users that we have in firebase and push all users into different collection in firestore in React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to know that I have so many users in my firebase database that mean in the Authentication part of firebase not a part of any collection, I hope I am clear overe here. Now, I need all the users that we have in firebase authentication section and then push all users data into different collection using firestore let' say users collection.
So, here we don't have separate collection for users. I need to create users collection once we get the users data from firebase authentication section . Please guide me if someone know the answer

Answer (score 0):

> I need all the users that we have **in the Firebase Authentication service**

You'll need to use the Admin SDK which allows retrieving the entire list of users in batches, see the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users). This is not possible with any of the Client SDK.

> And then push all users data into different collection using firestore
> let' say users collection

Then, you'll still use the Admin SDK to you will write to Firestore.

To use the Admin SDK you need to do it from a "privileged environment" (see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)), i.e. a server you manage or a Cloud Function.

Comment: Not a chance without Admin SDK right. So I can do one thing I guess like whenever anybody is going to register then I can create user collection so that might work in order to list down all user

Comment: Yes this is the other approach: Maintaining in Firestore (or the RTDB) a list of users in parallel to the list in the Auth Service. **But this mirroring has to be done from the first time you register a user in the Auth Service**. If you don't you'll have to use the Admin SDK.

Comment: Hey @James, did you have the time to look at the proposed answer?